# Primefaces SelectOneButton : Change individual button styles

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces selectOneButton. I want to make some buttons in that selectOneButton differently styled from others depending upon some backing bean value. Forexample text of 3 buttons in selectOneButton needs to be bold and that of remaining needs to be normal.

Is it possible?

Primefaces 3.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "standard" way to do this. The common workaround is to have multiple elements - `SelectItem` in your case - that are styled differently -  and use an expression with the `rendered` attribute to determine which ones are visible. This works for any component library, not only primefaces.

EDIT : have tried it right now - looks like I cannot influence the styling of the selectitems at all - at least not declaratively in the page. One could try tweaking the theme or overriding the primefaces selectors with custom styling using `!important` rule. But you would still not get distinct styling for the selectitems.

So please excuse my former confidence and regard this answer as a "No, you can't".

Comment: Hmm it's a valid question, why would you want to delete it? A "no, you can't" is a valid answer too. Maybe/hopefully it will prevent someone having the same issue from wasting time and effort.

Answer (score 9):

This is how i made it:

Add a styleClass to the selectOneButton:

```
<p:selectOneButton styleClass="yourStyleClass" value="#{yourBean.yourValue}" > ...
```

And then in the stylesheet you can get ahold of the rendered buttons like following (I added an icon to each of the buttons - do whatever you like):

```
.yourStyleClass div:first-child span {
    background-image: url('logo.png') !important;
    background-position: left center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-left: 6px;
    padding-left: 23px;
}

.yourStyleClass div:nth-child(2) span {
    background-image: url('picture.png') !important;
    background-position: left center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-left: 6px;
    padding-left: 23px;
}

.yourStyleClass div:nth-child(3) span {
    background-image: url('video.png') !important;
    background-position: left center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-left: 6px;
    padding-left: 23px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I haven't tested this but I'm pretty sure you can do it with the Primefaces Request Context. See this link:
[RequestContext](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/requestContext.jsf)

This will let you execute client side JavaScript from your backing bean.

So, determine which buttons need to change in your backing bean and then call a JS function that uses jquery's addClass function to add a CSS class to the buttons that need to be styled.

It seems simple enough in my head but I don't have time to test it right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with Jquery!!

```
<p:selectOneButton value="#{selectOneView.productViewOption}" styleClass="product-view">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="Xbox One" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="PS4" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="Wii U" />
</p:selectOneButton>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.product-view div:nth-child(1) span').addClass('fa fa-list fa-2x');
    $('.product-view div:nth-child(2) span').addClass('fa fa-star fa-2x');
    $('.product-view div:nth-child(3) span').addClass('fa fa-th fa-2x');
</script>
```